# Sort Datatables columns by subset of all columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Currently I have a table that contains all columns that we possibly want to show. What I would like to do is move a subset up to the front and hide all other columns. Basically what it looks like is this:

[Title, Name, DOB, Address, House Type, Salary] etc.

I would like to be able to pass a subset of this list

[Name,House Type, Salary]

and for to sort the list like so

[Name,House Type,Salary,Title,DOB,Address]

However due to the way datatables deals with colReorder it seems like I cannot access the table by title, but instead only by index, which on redraw updates. So I would need to create some sort of map maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/colReorder.order()), you can pass a second parameter to `colReorder.order` to use the original indexes (instead of the indexes from the last reordering). So, as long as you know the original index of each named column, you will be able to reorder them. Like so:

```
var originalOrder = [
    "Title", "Name", "DOB", "Address", "House Type", "Salary"
];

var getNewOrder = function(columns){
    var indexes = [];

    // Search for the index of the named column
    for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++){
        indexes.push(originalOrder.indexOf(columns[i]));
    }

    // Add the rest of indexes in their original order
    for (var i = 0; i < originalOrder.length; i++){
        if (indexes.indexOf(i) < 0){
            indexes.push(i);    
        }
    }
    return indexes;
};

// Pass it true so colReorder knows these are original indexes
table.colReorder.order(getNewOrder(["Name","House Type", "Salary"]), true);
```

You can see a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/angelalb/28xpcn34).